# Converted velocity to freemarker but not working

Tags: jsp, liferay, freemarker, velocity

I have created a structure and template for a web-content to publish an article thru Asset Publisher.

The Structure Source and View goes like below:

```
{
    "availableLanguageIds": [
        "en_US"
    ],
    "defaultLanguageId": "en_US",
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": {
                "en_US": " File Title "
            },
            "predefinedValue": {
                "en_US": "  "
            },
            "style": {
                "en_US": ""
            },
            "tip": {
                "en_US": "  "
            },
            "dataType": "string",
            "indexType": "keyword",
            "localizable": true,
            "name": "File_Title",
            "readOnly": false,
            "repeatable": true,
            "required": true,
            "showLabel": true,
            "type": "text",
            "nestedFields": [
                {
                    "label": {
                        "en_US": " Select File "
                    },
                    "predefinedValue": {
                        "en_US": "  "
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "en_US": ""
                    },
                    "tip": {
                        "en_US": " Browse the file from  NEWS folder present under Disney "
                    },
                    "dataType": "document-library",
                    "fieldNamespace": "ddm",
                    "indexType": "keyword",
                    "localizable": true,
                    "name": "Select_File",
                    "readOnly": false,
                    "repeatable": false,
                    "required": true,
                    "showLabel": true,
                    "type": "ddm-documentlibrary"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

View:

[image]

Now the Source for Template which is tagged to above structure was working well in Liferay 6.2 in velocity language goes like below:

```
#if (!$File_Title.getSiblings().isEmpty())
    #foreach ($cur_File_Title in $File_Title.getSiblings())
        <h3>
         <a href="$cur_File_Title.Select_File.getData()" target="_blank">$cur_File_Title.getData()</a>
        </h3>
        #end
#end
```

Once, I have migrated my application to DXP 7.2 and used the same structure and template (selected the same .vm templating language) in my application, the structure view in asset publisher is not allowing me to enter any values in the text box.

[image]

So, I tried to migrate the Velocity code to freemarker language as below.

```
<#if File_Title.siblings?size !=0>
    <#list File_Title.siblings as cur_File_Title>
        <h3>
            <a href="${cur_File_Title.Select_File.data}" target="_blank">${cur_File_Title.data}</a>
        </h3>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Now the structure view is allowing me to enter the values, but the attachment is not being shown when I tried to click on the published article.
[image]

Below is the screen, how it is currently appearing in 6.2, the anchor link have an document-media URL to download the attachment.
[image]

Comment: Can you describe "not working" with a few more words please? Any log, error message?

Comment: @Olaf Kock It's not preparing the correct href url to open the attachment which I am uploading.

Comment: Sorry, more detail: "not the correct url": Please give: *steps to reproduce *what do you observe? *what do you see? It'll be a lot easier to help you just from looking at the question if you give as much detail as possible, it'll make the question relevant and searchable for others that run into the same problem later, and it'll not require volunteers to guess/try/reproduce on their own. [ask] has quite some tips on questions. And please edit your question with that information rather than just commenting.

Comment: @OlafKock I have updated the question with detailed information.

Comment: I can see a valid URL being generated (`<a href="/documents.....`). What's the expected result, as you say "not the correct href url"?

Comment: @OlafKock the url is being generated correctly in 6.2 but in 7.2 the structure is not letting me enter any value in the text fields. If I am changing the template from Vm to ftl in 7.2, it’s letting me enter the values but after publish the article the href url is not present there. The working copy you see was from 6.2.